# Do public class & methods slow down your code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

My teacher ve always said that we shouldn't write the same part of code more than once while programming. But should a code which priority is to be robust & **quick**  use class and methods instead of write down the same code ever and ever?! Does calling a class take a little bit more of time than a direct code?!

For example if i want to do that:

```
Program1.Action1();
Program1.Action2();
Program1.Action3();
& 
Program2.Action1();
```

etc etc etc

and I want these actions to be perform the quickest as possible, May I call actions() or write down the full code?!

Adnt his question lead to an another one: 
For a a project we need to make it easily readable by the teacher so we have a lot of "class tab" on visual studio, we make everything public and we call our class or methods in our mainform.

Ok it's quite organized, very easy to read, BUT doesn't make the code slow down?!
Does public "class tab" are slower than a private class in our mainform?! 
I didn't find anything conlusive anywhere.. Thank you.

Comment: You won't be able to detect any performance differences. The compiler can also do this in an optimization technique called **inlining**, see [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/inline-optimization).

Comment: Knuth said it best:  "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Comment: The way to be *productive* is to not continually ask "is this code the fastest it can possibly be?" but to ask "is this code fast *enough*?" But the only way to answer that question is to set clear *goals* and then to *measure*.

Comment: Try googling 'premature optimization'

Comment: Raaah my program works fine, and meet my expectation. It is NOT premature optimization. (very interesting article though :) ) I just want to win some millisecond ... (and still be robust)

Comment: If every millisecond counts *and* you've isolated that it's *this* part of your code that is the bottleneck, then you write it both ways (and many others you may come up with) and *measure* which performs best, given *your* overall program, *your* data, etc. You **cannot** just sit down, learn a set of "rules" that are 100% true, and just blindly apply them, and the end result will always be the best performing code possible. Sorry, programming just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Please Damien stop doing that. 
Check up theory and what people say on a subject before practice is a **common** thing.
Reprogramming my code will take hours, and i wanted to be sure it would be worth it (to try) before doing it, that's it. I don't have a lot of experience, i don't really understand how compiling works. 
 Don't you really think i wouldn't ve measured the difference and apply it blindly?! 
Stop assume people are stupid, we don't have the same knowledge or experience about programming, I just ask a question which could  make me save a LOT of time. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Jrsls read the post by Damien carefully, because it has a point. Especially if you never profiled your code. Search for performance profiling .Net code: a good profiler (I had good experience with Jetbrains dotTrace) can save you weeks of blind guesses. Try it! You'll thank Damien after that ;)

Comment: stop assume people are stupid - I'm not. Really. I just recognize a particular stage that a **lot** of developers go through - normally after getting burned by something that performs badly. They decide to set out on a trail to learn how to write code that will always perform as best it can. They seek to learn "the rules" for always writing X rather than writing Y. What takes time to learn is that there *is* no set of such rules. Or if there are, they contain so many caveats, and number in the millions, such that you'll never be able to learn them all. I'm trying to help you move beyond that.

Comment: If I may ask, how is the rest of the code? Could you share a signicative part of it? To get a better grasp of what you may accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one main question and some concerns.

Let me address them separately; first: public and private are not, per se, faster or slower. The compiler *could*, in theory, optimize more when private methods are involved, but I don't think there are many cases when that could make a difference. So, the short answer is **NO, public does not slow down your code**.

A simple function call has negligible cost. If you're not programming some number-crunchink code looping over and over million and million of times, the cost of some function call is no concern.

So, if you don't have performance problems, you should not care about them. Do yourself a favor, while learning, and write this down 10 times: if you don't have performance problems, you should not care about them.

You should concentrate about code readability and algorithmic complexity, not about micro optimizations which may or may not improve "performance", but can easily complicate the code and create bugs.

*Easy to read and test* is paramount in (dare I say it?) 98% of the software developed.

Comment: The first aim of my program is definitely speed, i need to gain some ms, 2 or 3 would be perfect. So yes i have performance problem so i should care about it!  After you made your point very clear, I promess I will never care about performance if I don't have problem with them!
Anyway thank you for your responce !!

Comment: Are your method calls in a tight loop? Are you using the best algorithm possible? Did you profile your code? Performance optimization without profiling is like trap shooting in the dark.

Comment: i gonna try valgrind today. I didn't actually know performance optimization... it gonna be a BIG help thank you ! (that is exactly what i need !)

Comment: Usually, the best road to get a fast and robust program is, first, care about making it work and making it easy to read. Then finding bottlenecks through profiling, then optimizing only the relevant portions, which follow the 90-10 rule (10 percent of your code requires the 90% execution time, so go for that and ignore the rest). By personal experience, I can say that the 10% to be optimized rarely is the one you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

You could always consider *profiling* the performance.

But really, you ought to trust that C# will be better than you at making such choices when compiling your code.

The things you state in your question seem like unnecessary micro-optimisations to me that will probably not make a scrap of difference.

Readability and the ability to scale your program are more important considerations: computers are tending to double in speed every year but programmers are getting more and more expensive.

Comment: Every ms is a big win for me so every little scrap of difference is good for me :)  
and yes as you surely notice i don't quite well understand how compiling works, what's why i asked it.